# Transfer Files from no-video (broken) Windows 7 PC to another usable PC?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, file-transfer

How do I transfer files from my old video-card destroyed Sony to my new laptop using Windows 7 also?

I have the belkin easy transfer usb cable but that won't work since I need to activate it on the old pc. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Take the hard drive out of the non-functioning system and mount it on the working system by attaching it to the other system with a USB hard drive adapter, or internally using the IDE or SATA bus.
2. If the system can boot into Windows and connect to a network, then turn the system on and wait for it to finish booting.  Then using an Administrator account for that system access the drives over the network.

Drives are shared and accessible with an administrator account using

```
\\[The_Name_Of_System]\[DriveLetter]$
```

So, for a system named `MyLaptop` and file on the C drive, the path would be

```
 \\MyLaptop\C$
```

Answer (score 0):

There are fairly cheap kits you can purchase that will allow you to remove the drive from the laptop, and make it a USB drive from another machine.  I bought one on amazon 2 years ago for $10, it finally died, so I got the same one for $3 this year.

I am fairly new to superuser, so I am not sure if I am supposed to post external links, but just do a quick search for USB sata adapter, or USE IDE adapter and most you will find will do all types of drives.  Best investment I have gotten in a long time.